# Java char comparison does not seem to work

Tags: java, comparison, char, conditional-statements

I know you can compare chars in Java with normal operators, for example `anysinglechar == y`. However, I have a problem with this particular code:

```
do{ 
    System.out.print("Would you like to do this again? Y/N\n");
    looper = inputter.getChar();
    System.out.print(looper);
    if(looper != 'Y' || looper != 'y' || looper != 'N' || looper != 'n')
        System.out.print("No valid input. Please try again.\n");
}while(looper != 'Y' || looper != 'y' || looper != 'N' || looper != 'n');
```

The problem should not be the other method, inputter.getChar(), but I'll dump it anyway:

```
private static BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
public static char getChar() throws IOException{
    int buf= read.read();
    char chr = (char) buf;
    while(!Character.isLetter(chr)){
        buf= read.read();
        chr = (char) buf;
    }
    return chr;
}
```

The output I'm getting is as follows:

```
Would you like to do this again? Y/N
N
NNo valid input. Please try again.
Would you like to do this again? Y/N
n
nNo valid input. Please try again.
Would you like to do this again? Y/N
```

As you can see, the char I put in is an `n`. It is then printed out correctly(hence it is to be seen twice). However, the comparison doesn't seem to become true.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Have you tried if (a.equals(b)) ?

Comment: @CássioGalvão `(a.equals(b))` will work fine if its String. but for chars `==` is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect.  It is always `true` that `looper` isn't `'Y'` *or* it isn't `'y'` *or* it isn't ...

You want the logical operator for "and": `&&`

```
if(looper != 'Y' && looper != 'y' && looper != 'N' && looper != 'n')
```

and a similar change in your `while` condition.

Comment: Oh damnit. I knew it was something obvious. Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fix the logic operator from `||` to `&&`, make the code clearer:

```
private static final Set<Character> YES_OR_NO = Set.of('Y', 'y', 'N', 'n');

do { 
    System.out.print("Would you like to do this again? Y/N\n");
    looper = inputter.getChar();
    System.out.print(looper);
    if (!YES_OR_NO.contains(looper))
        System.out.print("No valid input. Please try again.\n");
} while(!YES_OR_NO.contains(looper));
```